# Wordpress wrong dates bug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress version 5.4.

I have a problem with the dates in a CPT, and it is that the dates show one day less.

Example: If I put in the backend the date, **08/18/20**, in the frontend it shows me **08/17/20**

I think for some reason the **date_i18n** function is not executing correctly.

This is the code where I show the dates:

```
<time><?php if (isset($event_from_date) && $event_from_date <> '') echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), strtotime($event_from_date)) . ','; ?></time>
```

Comment: Are your time zone and date settings correct in the admin page?

Comment: Maybe the timezone on your server is off? Using gmdate instead of date might help. What is in the `$event_from_date` variable?

Comment: Yes Sir. @j08691

Comment: This $event_from_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, "px_event_from_date", true); @admcfajn

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the *value* of `get_option('date_format')` and `$event_from_date` where the code doesn't work.